# How to know a window closed using javascript from another window/tab?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a window `example.com/welcome.php`.
Using `window.open(abcd.php,"mywindow","...")` I open `abcd.php` in new window.

By using `window.close()` from `abcd.php`. I close `abcd.php`. How can I trigger some action in `welcome.php` when `abcd.php` closed,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`onunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload) event attached to the opened window;

```js
var w = open('stackoverflow.com');
w.onunload = (ev) => {
    console.log('unload', ev);
};
//w.close();
```

**Update**

Set `unload` even inside `load` event to prevent from unnecessary firing `unload` on window open, witch happen to me in chrome at least.

```js
var w = open('https://stackoverflow.com/users/8424614/unnamedxaer');
w.onload = () => {
    w.onunload = (ev) => {
        console.log('unload', ev);
    };
};
```

**Update 2**

The urls have to be in the same domain to work, otherwise you will get an error when trying to attach event to opened window (`w`) (set debugger in the line with `onunload`), they also must be served from same kind of server - **not** accessed like files when the url in browser looks like this `c:/my-site/welcome.php`.

[Here is working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-galois-48wjf?file=/welcome.html). Open CodeSandbox's console located at the bottom of the window below the browser section to see output.

Comment: Nothing Happened when the window/tab is closed.

Comment: I added the Update 2 section, maybe it will help you.

Comment: Ok. I was trying from my local disk. It worked fine from my website... Thank you so much...